# How to handle mouse click on the canvas and resize the canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mvvm

I need to bring the application to the pattern MVVM.
Tell me how to refuse events in code-behind.
And when I click the mouse I have to get the coordinates of the point. When changing the size of the canvas - the new height and width.

Comment: You don't need to refuse all events from code behind when moving to MVVM. Some GUI related events are still valid. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051375/wpf-mvvm-using-events-is-a-bad-tone) question.

Comment: How can I contact event in code-behind with my ViewModel?
DataContext of View associated with ViewModel in Xaml.

<UserControl.Resources>
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:WeekViewModel}">
   <userControls:WeekControl DataContext="{Binding}"></userControls:WeekControl>
</DataTemplate>