# What is the Background color of a Menu/MenuItem in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menu

Apologies upfront for such a simplistic question.  However, my google-fu skills just aren't working today and every result I'm getting is explaining how to "change the default background", which is not what I need.

What color is the default of the WPF `MenuItem`?  Though I am interested in knowing the default color name, a better solution would be to know how to reference a Windows System brush value so that if the user changes their Windows theme settings, it would update this color, along with my menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the colors or set them? Getting is easy:

```
SystemColors.MenuBrush
SystemColors.MenuColor

SystemColors.MenuBarBrush
SystemColors.MenuBarColor

SystemColors.MenuTextBrush
SystemColors.MenuTextColor
```

And if you want to be alerted when the theme changes, see [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360671/detect-system-theme-change-in-wpf).

To get the default `MenuItem` style, this will work:

```
var style = FindResource(typeof(MenuItem)) as Style;
```

Then I'm afraid you'll have to rifle through it in the watch window to see what it's setting to what.

Comment: Odd, I found documentation referencing these colors but the output is different.  I'm building a control that has a menu on top, and some additional features below.  I've tried all of these colors, and they are all off.

Comment: @RLH The default Windows 7 style seems to do something different. The template uses `Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"` on the background `Rectangle`, but I don't know what's in the style. I found an "Edit in Blend" menu item somewhere in VS half an hour ago but I can't find it now.

Comment: View | "Design in Blend"

Comment: @RLH Well, you can get the default menu item style at runtime; see update. From there it doesn't seem like a lot of fun.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is probably close enough for my needs.