# Dynamically switch resource dictionaries to support high contrast mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, accessibility

I need to add support to a WPF application for Windows high contrast mode. What is the best way to detect high contrast mode is active, and load a specific resource dictionary (containing theme)?

Currently, the app looks the same in high contrast as normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine several things to achieve that. In WPF `SystemParameters.HighContrast` gives you information about the High Contrast accessibility feature. You can check that value and load the necessary resource dictionaries. That will handle the startup. And you can use the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360771/12354911), listen theme changed event, and check the `SystemParameters.HighContrast` if it is different then the previous load appropriate dictionaries vice versa.