# Scrollspy exception for logo?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar which I want to dynamically change the active state when in different sections of my page. I have the click change working correct and mostly the scrollspy, however I cannot work out how I can 'remove' the selection once the user scrolls to the top. 
As my logo is separate from my list elements, I have got it to work with the 'clicking' (first line of js) but am having trouble relating with the scrollspy.

Basically, how can I still use the scrollspy with the logo (but not highlighting) while still relating the other items in the list?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navigationbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="navigationbar-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>

          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">LOGO HERE</a>
        </div>

          <!--Nav links, etc for toggling-->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><!--move the active for + sr for each active-->
                <li><a class="navi-link" href="#about">about. <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="navi-link" href="#projects">projects.</a></li>
                <li><a class="navi-link" href="#contact">contact.</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".navbar-brand").on("click", function(){
                 $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");

             });

            $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
                $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
             });

            $('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar' })


        });

</script> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude ID in Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766381/exclude-id-in-twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766381/exclude-id-in-twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy