# Bootstrap 4 scrollspy excluding id's

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have sections one after another, and in the middle of them I have aside without anchor leading to it. Problem is, that scrollspy is active with previous section. I would like to make scrollspy not showing anything active at that point and resume when next section with valid anchor will appear. I was trying solutions from [Exclude ID in Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766381/exclude-id-in-twitter-bootstrap-scrollspy) but they seems not work in bootstrap 4, I can't even catch trigger, that suppose to work by doing:

```
$('#nav-links').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () { 
// or $('#nav-links li').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
// or $('#nav-links li').on('activate',  function(){
    alert('sdsd'); // no alert, but scrollspy is working
})
```

How to make scrollspy work only when id's from navigation links are matching with id of an scrolling element, excluding other elements?

a) (partial help) How to catch scrollspy firing events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem a bit hackish, but I think this is the only way to achieve your desired behavior without modifying the `scrollspy` javascript itself.

The idea here is to create anchors for the aside elements as well, but make these anchors hidden. As the order of the menu items is not important for the `scrollspy`, these “unnecessary” menu items can be grouped and wrapped into a single hidden parent element. Check the snippet below.

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* Just basic styling */
#content > div {
    height: 50vh;
    padding: 15px;
}
#content > div:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
#content > div:last-child {
    height: 100vh;
}
.aside {
    background-color: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <nav id="navbar-scollspy" class="navbar navbar-light bg-light flex-column">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

                <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section-1">Section 1</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section-2">Section 2</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section-3">Section 3</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section-4">Section 4</a>

                    <!-- Hidden menu items for asides -->
                    <div class="d-none">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#aside-1">Aside 1</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#aside-2">Aside 2</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div id="content" class="col-9" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-scollspy">
            <div id="section-1">
                <h4>Section 1</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside-1" class="aside">
                <h4>Aside 1</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            
            <div id="section-2">
                <h4>Section 2</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            
            <div id="aside-2" class="aside">
                <h4>Aside 2</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="section-3">
                <h4>Section 3</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="section-4">
                <h4>Section 4</h4>
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

By the way, you can listen for the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event on the spied element (`[data-spy="scroll"]`) or any parent, including $('body') and $(document) like this:

```
$('[data-spy="scroll"]').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function(event) {
    console.log('activate.bs.scrollspy', event);
})
```

Comment: can you tell how to change color of navbar matching color of section?

Comment: I would set the colors in the css by setting the proper `.nav-link .active` selectors to match the color of the corresponding sections. I think scrollspy is not good in doing this dynamically.