# jQuery: How to put jQuery datepicker inside Bootstrap Popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I was trying to show jquery datepicker inside the bootstrap popover and tried the solution in [Datepicker inside bootstrap popover [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914530/datepicker-inside-bootstrap-popover) but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).popover({
  selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]',
  html: true,
  container: 'body'
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  $('#date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
  });
});
```

```css
.popover {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='popover' title='header' data-content='<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-7"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">Search by date <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" style="cursor:help;float: right;" title="Search the allocation by the date the file is parsed. Only the parsed or allocated file will be shown by that date."></span></div><div class="panel-body"><div id="bootsdt"></div></div></div></div></div>'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: nope. no errors in the console.

Comment: You are initializing as `$('#date').datepicker({` where as I don't see that element there inside your `popover html`, but I see a div with `id=bootsdt` So Initialize with that id as `$('#bootsdt').datepicker({`

Comment: ow! so it's a typo error. Thank you @Guruprasad Rao .

Comment: Yep.. Anytime Happy coding.. :)