# how do you get the $this properties/attribute of bootstrap to be used as parameters

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-objects

How do i get the this property of the popover for twitter bootstrap parameter values, like i need to get the list item attribute i.e. data-boothtype to be used in bootstrap popover title? data-title is not enough though

**HTML**

```
<li class="booth" data-boothnumber="46" data-boothtype="prime" style="left: 240px; top: 30px;">46</li>
```

**JS**

```
$('.booth').popover({title: this.data-boothtype + "'s Booth", content: "test", placement: "right", callback:function(){ console.log(this)}});
```

PS:
The callback function is a test unit from [Callback function after tooltip / popover is created with twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694930/callback-function-after-tooltip-popover-is-created-with-twitter-bootstrap)

```
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  tmp.call(this);
  if (this.options.callback) {
    this.options.callback();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
ok here narrowed down: http://jsfiddle.net/tHHQ6/

Comment: `this.data-boothtype` wouldn't even be valid JavaScript code. It's important to get the very basics first...

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for that anyways, just the idea of calling the object's propert(ies)... and maybe i missed a much of the basics aside from that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
$('.booth').each(function(i, v){
    var $el = $(v);
    $el.popover({
        title: 'test' + $el.data('boothnumber'), 
        content: "test", 
        placement: "right"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tHHQ6/1/)

Comment: i'd never thought that calling a dom recursively and each given a property w/c is accessible directly is a good idea, thanks for this anyways, here have an upvote :)

Comment: in this case that is the only way since the title has to be found out dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you could do something like:

```
$('.booth').data('boothnumber')
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for the .data() api

Comment: the question might be misleading though, sorry for that and thanks anyway. I just wanted the current($this) data to be used in the bootstrap popover title... here let me help you help me :) http://jsfiddle.net/tHHQ6/