# Bootstrap Datepicker is displaying behind popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to display a datepicker in a popover (using bootstrap and bootstrap-datepicker extension) and having some issues, 
first I had a problem with displaying the datepicker and found this topic : [Datepicker in Popover Won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694930/callback-function-after-tooltip-popover-is-created-with-twitter-bootstrap/)
,but now it's displaying behind my popover so it's not fully visible

Here is the HTML code :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pop_doleance" rel="popover" data-original-title="Ajouter doléance">Ajouter doléance</button>

<div style="display: none" class="pop_doleance_content">
<form class="well form-inline form_doleance">
    <label for="date">Date : </label>
    <input id="date" type="text" class="input-medium">
</form>
```

And the Javascript code :

```
var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function (){
    tmp.call(this);
    if (this.options.callback) {
    this.options.callback();
    }
}

$(function (){
    $(".pop_doleance").popover({
        placement:'bottom', 
        html : true, 
        content: function(){return $('.pop_doleance_content').html();},
        callback: function(){$('#date').datepicker();}
    });  
});
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set popup's z-index to a lower value.

```
.popup { z-index : 900; }
```

and set datepicker's container z-index to a higher value like in case of jquery ui datepicker set

```
.ui-datepicker-div { z-index: 999; }
```

Comment: So I tried your solution.  
HTML : `<div id="divdate">  
<label for="date">Date : </label>  
<input id="date" type="text" class="input-medium"><br/>  
</div>`  
CSS : `.pop_doleance { z-index: 900; }  
.pop_doleance_content { z-index : 933; }  
.form_doleance { z-index: 966; }  
#divdate { z-index: 999; }`  
Tell me if I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant in the first time, I just had to create a z-index for the .datepicker class of the extension. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

In the css I added:

```
.datepicker { 
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Note the "!important". It did not work without this.

Comment: `z-index: 9999 !important;` is worked for me