# Using fullcalendar in a bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm currently using bootstrap 2.3.2, and I want to add a popover containing a calendar (using fullCalendar) in the navbar.

In order to do so, I created a nav item (called "timeTop"), and add a popover, using html option for content.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <form class="navbar-search pull-right">
            <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a id="timeTop" href="#">11:37</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding the calendar was the next step :

```
$('#timeTop').popover({
    "placement" : "bottom",
    "html" : true,
    "title" : "fullcalendar",
    "content" : function () {
        var contentHolder = $('<div />');
        var calendar = $('<div />', {
            "id" : "calendar"
        });
        calendar.fullCalendar({});
        contentHolder.append(calendar);
        return contentHolder.html();
    }
});
```

This work (my calendar is correctly added to my popover), but I'm encountering a display problem. My popover doesn't show my calendar, only the headers.

I made a fiddle reproducing my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/rqhWR/5/

Here, I have 2 calendars :

- one in the popover, showing only the calendar header.
- one in the main div, also showing only the calendar header.

(This seems to be the same problem. Using the code in a local page will show the main content containing the calendar, and the popover containing only the headers).

I'm aware of the existence of fullCalendar('render'), but I couldn't make it work in my case (I don't know when my popover is displayed).

My goal is to have a fullcalendar for the popover, with a result like this :
http://jsfiddle.net/pYGBm/75/

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 issues. First, the version of fullcalendar you were using (1.5.1) is out of date. Updating to 1.6.4 fixed the problem of the main calendar not loading.

The second problem seems to be caused by the fact that when the calendar is initialized, it isn't actually visible yet, so I'm guessing there are some issues calculating widths/heights. Initializing the calendar after the popover is created seems to fix this. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727204/76710), I was able to add a callback to the popover creation.

You can see the updated working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rqhWR/9/

```
var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  tmp.call(this);
  if (this.options.callback) {
    this.options.callback();
  }
}

$('#timeTop').popover({
    "placement" : "bottom",
    "html" : true,
    "title" : "fullcalendar",
    "content" : function () {
        var contentHolder = $('<div />');
        var calendar = $('<div />', {
            "id" : "calendar"
        });
        contentHolder.append(calendar);
        return contentHolder.html();
    },
    callback: function() { 
      var calendar = $("#calendar");
      calendar.fullCalendar({});
    }
});

$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({});
```

There are still some issues (i.e. calendar re-initializes each time you click the popover--may not be desirable)  and code cleanup needed, but I hope this is a step towards what you're trying to accomplish.