# Bootstrap 3 popover callback on hidden event not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, callback, bootstrap-popover

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694930/callback-function-after-tooltip-popover-is-created-with-twitter-bootstrap), i tried to implement a hidden callback function but while `show` callback works perfectly, there's no way to make `hidden` callback work. Can someone explain why this happens?

I've created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow2ms743/) to replicate the problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showCb = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
  $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
    showCb.call(this);
    if (this.options.showCb) {
      this.options.showCb();
    }
  }
  
  var hiddenCb = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hidden;
  $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hidden = function () {
    hiddenCb.call(this);
    if (this.options.hiddenCb) {
      this.options.hiddenCb();
    }
  }
  
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    showCb: function() {
      alert('showCb');
    },
    hiddenCb: function() {
      alert('hiddenCb');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've created a new [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmq7oxrb/) to show Christos's second snippet applied to Bootstrap's [jQBTK](https://github.com/mafu-d/jqbtk) plugin. This plugin takes advantage of Bootstrap's Popovers to create a virtual keyboard.
Problem: events are bind to the dynamically created object and so they fires multiple times. How can this be optimized?

Comment: Did you try my updated answer if it's working?

Comment: @ChristosLytras partially...I started testing yesterday evening and in my page the click trigger seems to be not working, there must be some conflict with other click events configured...so I managed just now to make it work with the manual trigger.

Answer (score 0):

At `hiddenCb` the prototype function is named `hide` and not `hidden` like you have in your code, so `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hidden` have to be `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide`.

These prototype functions are the [methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#methods) of the `popover` and not the [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#events). There is a method [`.popover('hide')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#popoverhide) but there is no method `hidden`. Your code is working because `popover` calls the methods `show` and `hide` and not by firing the events.

The [code you found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727204/1889685) is actually a *hack* that hooks/changes default `show` and `hide` methods to trigger your functions along with the `popover` default code, which is not so ideal when you want to handle these events.

To make it work in your code, change `hidden` method to `hide`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showCb = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
  $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
    showCb.call(this);
    if (this.options.showCb) {
      this.options.showCb();
    }
  }
  
  var hiddenCb = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide;
  $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide = function () {
    hiddenCb.call(this);
    if (this.options.hiddenCb) {
      this.options.hiddenCb();
    }
  }
  
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    showCb: function() {
      alert('showCb');
    },
    hiddenCb: function() {
      alert('hiddenCb');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

However, if you want to properly handle `show.bs.popover`, `shown.bs.popover`, `hide.bs.popover` and `hidden.bs.popover` events, then you should do it by using `on` and much simpler code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[data-toggle=popover]")
    .popover()
    .on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
      alert('showCb!');
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
      alert('hiddenCb!');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

For [jQBTK](https://github.com/mafu-d/jqbtk) you just use `click` `trigger` and then use the events. That will trigger each shown/hidden events only once:

```
$('input').keyboard({
  trigger: 'click',
})
.on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
  console.log('shownCb!');
})
.on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
  console.log('hiddenCb!');
});
```

Check this working [jsFiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/lytrax/yabguqr4/2/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still having troubles. I've update the question with another jsFiddle showing your second snippet applied to jQBTK Bootstrap's plugin. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Mark you haven't mention anywhere in your question anything about [jQBTK](https://github.com/mafu-d/jqbtk), your question is *"Bootstrap 3 popover callback on hidden event not working"* and I think I answered that why your code didn't work. So to answer your second question, why jQBTK isn't working, it's because it doesn't bind any events to `popover`, you have to alter the code of it **or use the first method you found** using `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show` and `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hide`. Isn't that work for you now using `hide` instead of `hidden`?

Comment: I didn't mention it because I was trying to simplify the situation. In first fiddle I was using the plain popover plugin and was experimenting problem already there so I asked the question about popover, not about jQBTK. By the way, first code you are suggesting to use have the same problem that I'm reporting in the question update: callbacks are being stacked and called multiple times (the more popover I open, the more callbacks are being called...dismitting popover does not dismit the callback).

Comment: When you have a problem, you must describe the whole problem **with simplified code** and not break/mention a part of it **that you think** it's the culprit. Your updated request *"How can this be optimized?"* is unclear of **what you're asking**, **what your problem is** and **what you want to achieve**.

Comment: In my opinion is everything there and I don't know how else to explain: i'm asking a way to catch a hidden callback on a popover, my problem is (using your suggestion) that callbacks are being stacked and called several times at once, i want to achieve what I'm asking. I'm not english native but if there's a specific point unclear, tell me what it is and I try to explain better.

Comment: @Mark the suggestion is yours, is not mine. You had a problem and you found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694930/callback-function-after-tooltip-popover-is-created-with-twitter-bootstrap) hooking `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show` and `$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.hidden` and your problem **at first** was *"Bootstrap 3 popover callback on hidden event not working"*. I gave a complete answer on why it wasn't working and gave you a solution and a *proper* way to do what your question describes. Then you changed the question and **you added a problem about jQBTK**.

Comment: @Mark I wouldn't do that in other cases, but I understand that you may have some trouble using English language and again you're not so experienced Stackoverflow user. English is not my native language either and I can understand you. So, I have updated my answer with a working code for **jQBTK** that it triggers the `shown`/`hidden` events only once. There is also a working jsFiddle, check it out.