# jQuery plugin function override

Tags: jquery, plugins, overriding

I need to override function **showEventsList** from jQuery plugin [bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/js/calendar.js#L982) to change it behavior.
I've tried to google function overriding in jQuery, but still can't find the right way to do this.

I always can to rewrite the plugin, but it's not interesting :(

Comment: Can't you just copy the file and rewrite it yourself?

Comment: Karl, it's not interesting. Non-standard task gives the possibility to learn something new and improve understanding.

Comment: Then i don't think you can. the only thing you can do is overide every prototype that use this function and call you own function.

Comment: Use $.extend, see this SO for an example [How to Extend Twitter Bootstrap Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137311/how-to-extend-twitter-bootstrap-plugin)