# Add function to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

how can I add a function to Bootstraps Modal?

e.g. I want to call:

```
mymodal.info("foo");
```

but this funtion obviously doesn't exist for the modal object.

I've included the bootstrap.js and tried to add the function like:

```
$.fn.modal.prototype.info = function (msg) {
  // test:
  console.log(msg);
}
```

in a scripts.js (included after bootstrap.js).
But this doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137311/how-to-extend-twitter-bootstrap-plugin

Comment: I've tried it with
`var _super = $.fn.modal;
$.extend(_super.Constructor.prototype.info, function () {
    console.log('test');
});`
But it doesn't work...