# How to extends bootstrap modal with custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

guys I have a question to you. How can I extend my bootstrap modal with my custom function. I don't know how to use this function extending this modal on $dialog or $body can someone give me some advice?

Can not add code here because the bootstrap modal box code is too long :/

Comment: Could you please describe the end result you are looking to accomplish? Do you have a code sample your working with that you could add to this question? An [MVCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm using bootstrap.js there is modal and I would like to extend this modal box not in boostrap.js file but in let's say my custom.js file without copying code from bootstrap.js and I would like to use my custom function on this bootstrap modal $dialog or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post as comment, so here goes as an answer.

Check this:

[How to Extend Twitter Bootstrap Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137311/how-to-extend-twitter-bootstrap-plugin)

I think this answer can help you.