# SystemColors.ActiveCaption Color Doesn't Match Actual Windows Title Bar Color

Tags: .net, visual-studio, colors, windows-8.1

According to MSDN on [SystemColors.ActiveCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.activecaption(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets a Color structure that is the color of the background of the active window's title bar.

---

I'm finding that no matter what theme I have set in Windows 8, in Visual Studio this color is always the same (some shade of blue).:

[image: Visual Studio ActiveCaption color (blue)]

In reality, my windows ActiveCaption is a shade of green:

[image: Actual ActiveCaption color (green)]

---

So, why the difference?  Where is Visual Studio pulling the ActiveCaption color (or the InactiveCaption, or any of the other system colors for that matter) if this value never changes?

Comment: Yup.  And it is in fact the color you get when you use the theme api to draw the caption.  There is no known way to reproduce the Windows 8 look.  Appcompat is rough.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660976/get-the-active-color-of-windows-8-automatic-color-theme) appears to be very similar.  However, [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560890/vista-7-how-to-get-glass-color) met my application's needs.

Comment: [This question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24600956/1730559) seems to be the only correct one which gives the proper blended titlebar color.