# How to change the windows title bar color using pywin32?

Tags: python, pyside2, pyside6

I'm developing an app using Pyside2 under windows (10 and 11) and I would like to switch / change the windows title bar color .

Microsoft say that it's possible to do that using win32api and I didn't find how to do that using pywin32api.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The title bar is drawn by Windows so you cannot change it via PyQt or Pyside. There are 2 ways to do it :

First one is with C++ : [See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310316/setting-title-bar-and-border-colors-programmatically)

The second one is: You can create your own title bar with Qt. Just disable the windows title bar, and create a top frame for your interface with clickable buttons from Qt Designer or from code.

Comment: Thanks Emrejik for your support

Comment: The C++ part could be implemented in python by using ctypes