# Get Accent color of window

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the accent color from window? Because I want to make the `ToolStrip` have the same color as accent color of window.
I searched it up on Google and all of them were some Windows Phone stuff or were not working.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: There is no such term in WinForms. Take a look at the [SystemColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) class for available system colors.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I meant this. Heres Imgur link: http://imgur.com/XERleXu

Comment: Try this: [Retrieving Windows 8 Theme Colours](https://www.quppa.net/blog/2013/01/02/retrieving-windows-8-theme-colours/).

Comment: There still is no such thing as an accent color in Winforms. The Color of the title bar is determined by the system color scheme; the rest is all up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint="#127")]
    internal static extern void DwmGetColorizationParameters(ref DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors colors);
}

public struct DWMCOLORIZATIONcolors
{
    public uint ColorizationColor, 
        ColorizationAfterglow, 
        ColorizationColorBalance, 
        ColorizationAfterglowBalance, 
        ColorizationBlurBalance, 
        ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity, 
        ColorizationOpaqueBlend;
}

private static Color GetWindowColorizationColor(bool opaque)
{
    var colors = NativeMethods.DwmGetColorizationParameters();

    return Color.FromArgb((byte)(opaque ? 255 : colors.ColorizationColor >> 24),
        (byte)(colors.ColorizationColor >> 16), 
        (byte)(colors.ColorizationColor >> 8), 
        (byte)colors.ColorizationColor);
}
```

If you also wanna update the color when it gets changed while your program is running please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670173/4000926) post!

Comment: where does the error go??? did you add the `System.Runtime:InteropServices` directive?

Comment: Have you ever run it? Please do. Hint: What is the type of the `params` variable (`var params = ...`)?

Comment: Well... not working...

Comment: Nice try, but the code is wrong. The answer you linked to has the correct code. In the future, please don't copy and paste code (incorrectly or not) from other answers. Just flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: does this handle xp win7 win8  altogether ?