# Get forecolor of text of title bar in Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to get the color of text of title bar in Windows 10 because I want to color some text of my form upon this color.

Because the color of windows in Windows 10 can change dynamically with the background, I need to get the text color of title bar for properly coloring my form.
For instance, if the Windows 10 color is yellow

[image]

the text is black, while if the color is blue

[image]

the text is white: I want the color of the text.

Where can I find it?

So far I properly set only the background color of my title bar with DWMCOLORIZATIONPARAMS through ColorizationColor, but I can not find a way to get the forecolor.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943023/501082) for exact algorithm and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13670173/501082) to get the accent color for the title bar. Works well on my side. Tested on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the `SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText` should be the one you need. This changes dynamically according to the current profile.

> Gets a Color structure that is the color of the text in the active
>   window's title bar.

Link: [SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.activecaptiontext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Already tried: not works. I've tried all colors from SystemColors and no one works